# Como converter array de strings para string?

Tags: c, arduino

Em um programa para o Arduino, eu tenho um array de strings mas parece que a função onde vou usar esse dado só aceita string. Como faço para converter um array em uma string ?

```
File prog = SD.open("prog.bin");
String leiaS(void){

    return String(prog.read());


 }


   digitalWrite(leia(), inverte(leiaS()));


String inverte(String port){
     if(digitalRead(port)==HIGH)
      return LOW;
     else
      return HIGH;
  }
```

Erro:

> could not convert 'leiaS' from 'String (*)()' to 'String'

Percebi que estava faltando um parênteses na chamada da função `leiaS`. Depois de corrigir e verificar apareceu o erro:

> cannot convert 'String' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' for argument '2' to 'void digitalWrite(uint8_t, uint8_t)'

Comment: Pelo que pesquisei, não existe função pronta. Eu iria de `loop` dentro do array e concatenaria uma string mesmo.

Comment: Sim, mas para isso acredito que precisaria saber o tamanho do array. Sei que tem 1 byte, pois a função read() lê 1 byte de cada vez. O problema é quanto vai ser isso em strings. Segundo a documentação a função sizeof() retorna o numero de bytes. Não sei se serve. Se pudesse exemplificar eu agradeço.

Comment: Carlos, vc está usando `String` onde se espera numerais, me parece que vc precisa reescrever todo o seu código para se ter o resultado que deseja.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`leiaS` esta definido como funcao (de tipo `String (*)(void)`)

```
String leiaS(void) { /* ... */ }
```

A referencia a `leiaS` na linha do `digitalWrite`

```
digitalWrite(leia(), inverte(leiaS)));
```

é como parametro para a funcao `inverte`.
Suponho que a funcao inverte esta definida como recebendo uma string: nao podes passar um ponteiro para uma funcao.

Comment: Deve ser isso. Tinha esquecido de colocar a função `inverte`. Atualizei.

Comment: Agora percebi que estava faltando um parenteses na função. Depois de corrigir, da o erro "
cannot convert 'String' to 'uint8_t {aka unsigned char}' for argument '2' to 'void digitalWrite(uint8_t, uint8_t)'"

Comment: agora tens o segundo parametro para funcao `digitalWrite` com tipo errado. A funcao esta definida para obter um valor de tipo `uint8_t` mas estas a passar um valor de tipo `String`. Este tipos nao sao compativeis, por isso o compilador nao pode fazer a conversao dum para o outro e da erro.

Comment: Troquei os retornos por `unsigned char` e resolveu

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer uma iteração e ir lendo cada caracter que o `read` retorna e ir adicionando num array de char.

```
char arrayLeitura[20];
int index=0; 
char charLeitura;

File prog = SD.open("prog.bin");
if (prog) {
    while (prog.available()) {
         charLeitura= prog.read();
         arrayLeitura[index++]=charLeitura;
    }
    prog.close();
}
```

Acredito que depois tu consegue dar um

```
return String(arrayLeitura);
```

Comment: O problema é que ai você está pegando mais de um byte. O byte na verdade é um numero. Só que parece que a função digitalWrite() só aceita string. E quando eu tento pegar um char e converter para string não funciona.

Comment: Dentro do `while` eu pego o byte e converto pra char, depois no final tu você pode fazer o meu return que vai retornar uma `String` dos array de `char`, você testou?

Comment: Tentei dessa forma `String leiaS(void){
    char bt = prog.read();
    char cod[1];
    cod[0] = bt;
    return String(cod);
    
  }`., que basicamente faz o mesmo, já que quero ler só um byte. Resulta no erro "could not convert 'leiaS' from 'String (*)()' to 'String'"